# Low Quality Wifi with TL-WDN3200(N600)

Tags: wireless

Recently I needed to install Ubuntu on my machine. The problem is that I'm getting a low-quality Wi-fi signal.

I'm using a "plug and play" wi-fi connector from TP-LINK: TL-WDN3200(N600).

How can I improve this?

Comment: Define *"low-quality"* please

Comment: Bad quality signal. The signal is weaker.

Comment: How do you know it's weaker? Judging by the icon or are you experiencing slower download/upload?

Comment: Both. Unfortunately. x.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a Terminal and enter:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
echo "options rt2800usb nohwcrypt=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800usb.conf 
sudo modprobe -rfv rt2800usb
sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Source: [Ubuntu Forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2354066&page=2)

Comment: how do you know this will work? Wireless problems are hardware specific

Comment: Why this should work? Can you explain? I'm using ubuntu 16.04 btw.

Comment: Update: I did this and removed what johnconnorfx suggested. The connection improved a lot. Not as good as my previous SO, but I had a nice improvement. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Miraculously, a user from omgubuntu.co.uk had written a comment in one of their articles announcing the release of 17.04 that fixed this issue. The comment is as follows:

> wifi and networkmanager
>
> The new NetworkManager release 1.4.0 adds new features to change the
>   current MAC address of your Ethernet or Wi-Fi card (spoofing/cloning).
>   As a debian "sid" user i understand that being on bleeding edge,
>   sometimes new features and configs can be Incompatible with my machine
>   hardware!!! Now being a ubuntu user i can see that Ubuntu is losing
>   his "user friendly" name and no more care for desktop users! This was
>   an unacceptable default config on Ubuntu's best days! Ubuntu haters
>   and criticists must be happy now!
>
> Edit the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file
>
> And add:
>
> ```
> [device]
> wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
> ```
>
> Restart the networkmanager service and use your wireless connection
>   :)"

This worked for me.

Comment: How do you know OP is using 17.04?

Comment: It didn't work. x.x